# Browser handling on 401 status

Tags: jquery, json, http, status, http-status-code-401

I been working on an application that  basically interaction with the server over json api (Not CORS request mind you just plain ajax request to server with accepting a json format back)

Now I have this feature where I need to logout a user if his/her token/session expired and way I handle this I render **401** status in the response header if that happen ever(token/ session expired)

Now what I not able to understand is that I render **401** status I sort of get redirected to the current location

`http://localhost:4005/payouts`

On Chrome Network Header I see this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxv9ih0s0r7vumy/Screenshot%202014-01-16%2018.04.46.png

**Caution: Provisional headers are shown**

At first I look to me that its chrome specify thing but I see the same thing happening in Firefox as well

Is that a standard behavior I even went through documentation([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-66)) of how  the web browser handle **401** status code and to be honest I cant find any where mentioning of the fact the they happen to redirection if certain challenge aren't met

Just Couple thing more request is

1. Ajax Request + JSON Request (Not a `CORS` request)
2. Below are my `Request / Response` Header

**Request Header**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4005/payouts/mark_as_paid.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1709
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_minerva_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWI2N2MyNDg5MTg5YjEzNmM2MGM2ZDM2MTNlYWEyNzc3BjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMVN3b3JvVTJCZzFkaU1xOWhKeTU0c2hPT2F6dVZzOEhvdStMWml1QUNQUW89BjsARkkiEWFjY2Vzc190b2tlbgY7AEZJIkVlMGVmODM3OGMxZDBlYTRmNGFiYTRhMzcyZGFkMGZiYzBlYTI5NGNkODYxOTRhOTk1NTYwYTA0MzliYTgyY2JmBjsAVEkiHHdhcmRlbi51c2VyLmRlZmF1bHQua2V5BjsAVFsHSSIJVXNlcgY7AEZACw%3D%3D--93e6c7c38e4798ca3a1fbe15485a22eba3f358a9
Host:localhost:4005
Origin:http://localhost:4005
Referer:http://localhost:4005/payouts
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Server:thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof
Set-Cookie:_minerva_session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWI2N2MyNDg5MTg5YjEzNmM2MGM2ZDM2MTNlYWEyNzc3BjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMVN3b3JvVTJCZzFkaU1xOWhKeTU0c2hPT2F6dVZzOEhvdStMWml1QUNQUW89BjsARkkiCmZsYXNoBjsARm86JUFjdGlvbkRpc3BhdGNoOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoCToKQHVzZWRvOghTZXQGOgpAaGFzaHsAOgxAY2xvc2VkRjoNQGZsYXNoZXN7BjoKYWxlcnRJIhNUb2tlbiBleHBpcmVkIQY7AFQ6CUBub3cw--a09dddd474e1201fec156c47d298e3189b6a4451; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id:be146be842651831d3903ab0db99bc5e
X-Runtime:0.016927
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

**JSON Response Data**

```
{"error":"Token expired!"}
```

Comment: Dropbox link is dead. That's why images should be inserted into posts on SO.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 response does not imply any kind of redirection.

(The relevant spec btw is http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-25.html)

Comment: Agreed I know `401` does not imply for redirection hence I'm not sure why the redirection is happening